# How to open a new component with button, FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, components

I've made a login form which is working perfectly. However, when I enter my credentials and I want to click on the login button, I want to open a new window (or component). Can someone help me?

What kind of statement should I add to my click handlers of my login button?
(component to proceed is called: feeds.mxml)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look into the concept of [ViewStack navigation containers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e4d.html), which handles pretty much what you want. You could also use [PopUpManager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html) to pop it open depending on your feeds.mxml class.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is usually to use a ViewStack.  Depending on your requirements you may also be interested in using a TabNavigator or just a custom component as the "authenticatedView" of your primary ViewStack.

Fx 3 example:

```
    <mx:ViewStack id="viewStack">

        <mx:Canvas id="nonAuthenticatedView"/>
            //Your login screen "stuff" can go here.
            //On a successful login: viewStack.selectedIndex = 1.
            //On logout set selectedIndex to 0 to return to the login screen.
        </mx:Canvas>

        <mx:Canvas id="authenticatedView">
            //Instead of a Canvas this could be whatever, another ViewStack, TabNavigator, custom component, etc.
        </mx:Canvas>

    </mx:ViewStack>
```

This can get a lot more sophisticated if you start using a singleton model, bindings, and so on, but this should get you started.